# Can't find a route for 'post: ta'

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make database CRUD editing in CodeIgniter 4 with Modal (Bootstrap 5), but I always get this error : **Can't find a route for 'post: ta'.** This line of code work fine ( add a record ) :

```
$routes->post('tambah-TA', 'Admin\Ahli::tambah_TA');
```

but this one (update a record) :

```
$routes->post('update-TA/(:any)', 'Admin\Ahli::update_TA/$1');
```

always throw error Can't find a route for 'post: ta'. I have checked syntax and backslash. These are the functions for add record and update in Ahli.php (controller) :

```
public function tambah_TA()
    {  
        $data = [            
            'nama' => $this->request->getPost('nama'),
            'alamat' => $this->request->getPost('alamat'),
            'no_ktp' => $this->request->getPost('no_ktp'),    
            'sipp' => $this->request->getPost('sipp'),
            'sipp_ed' => $this->request->getPost('sipp_ed'), 
            'str' => $this->request->getPost('sipp'),
            'str_ed' => $this->request->getPost('sipp_ed'),
            'kategori' => $this->request->getPost('kategori'),
            'perusahaan' => $this->request->getPost('perusahaan'),
            'kota' => $this->request->getPost('kota'),    
            'posisi' => $this->request->getPost('kota'),    
            'ijazahS1' => $this->request->getPost('ijazahS1'),
            's1_univ' => $this->request->getPost('s1_univ'),
            's1_thn' => $this->request->getPost('s1_thn'),
            'ijazahS2' => $this->request->getPost('ijazahS2'),
            's2_univ' => $this->request->getPost('s2_univ'),
            's2_thn' => $this->request->getPost('s2_thn'),
            'ijazahS3' => $this->request->getPost('ijazahS3'),
            's3_univ' => $this->request->getPost('s3_univ'),
            's3_thn' => $this->request->getPost('s3_thn')

           ];
         //  dd($data);
         //$ta = $this->taModel = new TAModel();  
          $success = $this->TAModel->tambahTA($data);
        if ($success) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data berhasil ditambah');
        }
    }
    public function update_TA($id) {
        $data = [            
            'nama' => $this->request->getPost('nama'),
            'alamat' => $this->request->getPost('alamat'),
            'no_ktp' => $this->request->getPost('no_ktp'),    
            'sipp' => $this->request->getPost('sipp'),
            'sipp_ed' => $this->request->getPost('sipp_ed'), 
           ];         
          $success = $this->TAModel->update($id, $data);
        if ($success) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data berhasil di-update');
        }
    }
```

Can anybody give me a clue ?

Comment: When and where exactly are you getting that error? And do you have a stack trace for that error you can add to the question (including the full error message)? I'm guessing that you're posting a form? Can you also show us how you defined the `action`-tag in that form?